# Can an event be triggered in Backbone once a collection has been fetched and rendered?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

After calling collection.fetch({ add: true }) on a Backbone collection, I'd like to trigger an event once the view of the updated collection has finished rendering.

The "[collection view](https://github.com/hubgit/hubmed/blob/gh-pages/js/views.js#L129)" has an "add" method, which generates an "[item view](https://github.com/hubgit/hubmed/blob/gh-pages/js/views.js#L157)" for each new item in the collection, calls "render" on that view, and adds it to the collection view.

Is there a way to trigger an event when fetching a collection has finished, and all items have been added and rendered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`fetch` method on collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) takes a `success` parameter:

> **fetch** `collection.fetch([options])`
>
> [...] The **options** hash takes `success` and `error` callbacks which will be passed (collection, response, options) and (collection, xhr, options) as arguments, respectively.

The `success` callback will be called *after* the collection has been updated so it will be called *after* all the `"add"` events have been triggered and dealt with. So you could do this:

```
collection.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response, options) {
        collection.trigger('fetched_and_notified');
    }
});
```

and anyone that cares could `collection.on('fetched_and_notified', ...)` to listen for such an event. If you wanted, you could provide your own `fetch` implementation to trigger this event automatically, something like this:

```
fetch: function(options) {
    options = options ? _.clone(options) : { };

    var success     = options.success;
    options.success = function(collection, response, options) {
        collection.trigger('fetched_and_notified', collection);
        if(success)
            success(collection, response, options);
    };
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger custom events on all kinds of objects whenever you want to based on your application using [Backbone.Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events)

To trigger an event after rendering the view,:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
     _.bindAll(this);
  },  

  render: function() {
     //Do all the rendering

     this.trigger('myEvent');
  }
});
```

[this.trigger('myEvent'](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger)) is the line that does the trick.

Comment: The problem is that the collection view doesn't have a "render" method; that only exists in each item view. The collection view (a single element) is created when the application starts up, and item views are added to it as they are loaded. I need to trigger the event after a batch of item views have been added. One possibility might be to trigger the event after a certain interval, resetting the timer as each item view is rendered.

Comment: Another hack might be to check if the view is the last in the collection. if(this.model == this.collection.at(this.collection.length-1)) and then trigger the event. Getting the timer interval right is complicated and might create future bugs.